# Unvalidated integer value is received from 'atoi'

Tags: c, klocwork

For the following code, klocwork reports **Unvalidated integer value 'val' is received from 'atoi' and can be used to access array**

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i = 0;
    int val = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < argc; i++)
    {
        if (argv[i])
        {
            val = atoi(argv[i]);
            ......
            ......
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I have no clue to solve this issue. If argv[i] is not a number then atoi will return 0. What is klocwork expecting here?

Comment: Do you use `val` as an array index somewhere? ( `xy[val]` )

Comment: what do you do with `val`?

Comment: Yes. I am using val as an array index in other piece of code

Comment: Then you could index it out of bounds without validate the `atoi` result as valid number between `0` and `sizeof(your_array)/sizeof (your_array[0])`

Comment: `if (val < 0 || val >= (sizeof xy/sizeof xy[0])) Handle_OutOfRangeIndex(val);`  Better to use `size_t val;` too.

Comment: Please show the code that is using val.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, the first obvious advice here is: stop using `atoi`. `atoi` is for sketching, not for real code. `atoi` does not have any failure feedback mechanisms and produces undefined behavior on overflow. Functions from `ato...` group have been semi-officially semi-abandoned in C95. Since that moment they have been just tagging along purely for backward compatibility. I have no idea why they are still not officially deprecated.

You want to convert a string to integer - use `strtol` and remember to check for errors by analyzing `errono` and/or the return value. And, as it has been already suggested, if you are using the resultant value as an array index, it is a good idea (and for a value that comes from the outside world - it is a must) to make sure the index is in the proper range.

Comment: Is there any official document supporting your statement about the desuse of the `ato*` group of functions? I'm a bit astonished by this.

Comment: @Rafael Campos Nunes: It is actually a known fact from the history of C language. In 1995 C language was updated with support for wide-characters. All character-related library functions got their wide versions (like `wcscpy` for `strcpy`, `wcstod` for `strtod` and so on). However, no wide version of functions from `ato...` group were ever created because at that time they were already considered subsumed by `strto...` functions. You can read about it in the rather well-known "C99 Rationale" document: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/C99RationaleV5.10.pdf (see 7.20.1.1)

Comment: @RafaelCamposNunes in the specification of the `atoi` function in the C Standard it says "If the value of the result cannot be represented, the
behavior is undefined"  (you can look this up by googling N1570)  . It's a natural conclusion that if a function has undefined behaviour that you can't control, then the function should not be used.

Answer (score 1):

It's warning you that you're using a tainted value to access an array later in your code. Have a look here for how to fix it.

https://developer.klocwork.com/documentation/en/insight/10-1/sv-tainted-call-indexaccess

Any input that you get needs to be validated in some way before use.

Answer (score 1):

**atoi** is define as:

```
int atoi (const char *nPtr)                 /*convert the string nPtr to int*/
```

You must keep in mind that if the converted value cannot be represented to int. the **atoi** function behavior will be **undefinned** (Use it with precaution).

**Updated**

If the converted value falls out of range of corresponding return type, the return value is undefined. If no conversion can be performed, ​0​ is returned.